# Topology, Hausdorff space and the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a Hausdorff topological space and Y be a subset of X. prove that the subspace topology on Y is Hausdorff.

I started this problem and it seems simple but I a confused on how to prove it. I know that we can just use the definition of being Hausdorff and the subspace topology but I am having a hard time writing it. 
any help would be great

Answer (score 6):

To show that a space is Hausdorff, all you have to do is show that for each pair of distinct points $x,y \in Y$ there exist disjoint open neighbourhoods $U,V \subset Y$ (w.r.t the subspace topology) such that $x \in U, y \in V$.

However, given any points $x,y \in Y$, certainly $x,y \in X$ so there are disjoint neighbourhoods $U',V'$ in $X$ such that $x \in U', y \in V'$. Now, let $U = U' \cap Y$ and $V = V' \cap Y$.

- Why are $U,V \subset Y$ open? (Hint : subspace topology definition)
- Why are they disjoint?
- Why is $x \in U, y \in V$?

Now you  see why $Y$ is Hausdorff.